# search and replace by groups R

Tags: r, search, replace, group-by

I am trying to search and replace with dplyr based on a group. I have this so far:

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(attribute = case_when(col1 == "Work" & (attribute == "B" | attribute == "C") ~ "", TRUE ~ attribute))
```

What i am trying to do is for each group of IDs to look if there is one "Work" string in col 1, "B" or "C" in attribut, then replace with "", otherwise keep what is in attribute. But what comes out is a search and replace not taking the groups in consideration.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `plyr` loaded in your environment? Try with `dplyr::mutate` instead or else add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
filteredData <- dataset %>%
  filter(col1 == "Work" & (attribute == "B" | attribute == "C"))

dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate(attribute = ifelse(ID %in% filteredData$ID, "", attribute))
```